# What DLNA keyword means in smartphone Communication spec?

Tags: iphone, pixel, smartphone, dlna

I could see DLNA in smartphone communication (COMMS) spec section for few phones like Nexus 6, Pixel 1, 2, 3 but, not for iPhones in gsmarena.com

https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=9350&idPhone2=9256&idPhone3=8858

What difference it makes if a phone doesn't support DLNA?

Comment: Did you do any research? There are lots of things explaining what DLNA means.

Comment: yes I did. phones which does not have that DLNA spec too works with TV's for casting and communicating media. That's what I did not understand why these phones only having DLNA on their spec?

Comment: There are many methods of media sharing/casting. Only some of them are related to DLNA. Also just the word "DLNA" in a spec list is pretty useless: it does not tell you anything about what the device can actually do.